# Have elements equally span entire width / height of their RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have, say three buttons i would like to list below one another in a layout. Depending on the device, screen size, pixel density, orientation and so on, i would like the buttons to span the entire height of their parent layout. The buttons each have a fixed height (dp), so the spanning is more likely concerning the space between the buttons.

I saw several questions on various forums regarding how a LinearLayout is supposedly a fix for this problem, by nesting a layout for each element, having the layout span. I would very much like to avoid nesting layouts, and I'm using a RelativeLayout as of now, so if there is any way to go about it with this type of layout it will be of great help! :)

Additionally, I would like the top and bottom button to "touch" the parent layout border at the top and bottom, and the last (or rest) button to fill out the rest of the vertical space equally.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you wish to achieve, but you should be able to do this using a `LinearLayout` & `weights` (so you don't have to nest multiple layouts).

If you want the 3 buttons to take up the entire parent of the screen just add a `weight` to each for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_three"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, but this centers buttons towards the vertical middle, I would like the top and bottom button to touch the parent layout border and the last (or rest) to fill out the rest equally.

Comment: Also, this stretches the buttons in order to fill the vertical space. I am trying to stretch the space between the buttons. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Try to set to `topButton` a field in `XML:
  android:layout_alignTop="true";`
- Try to set to `middleButton` a field in `XML:
  android:layout_centerVertical="true";`
- Try to set to `bottomButton` a field in `XML:
  android:layout_alignBottom="true";`

Comment: android:align_parent does not exist?

This might be true though for three buttons. If I want four or five buttons, this approach wont work quite as well? :/